# Angular Directive doesn't receive changes from component made in ngOnDestroy method

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-components, lifecycle

There's an unexpected directive behavior after component was destroyed.

Directive didn't get changes made in ngOnDestroy method in component

component :

```js
export class InfoButtonComponent implements OnDestroy {
    display = false;

    justMethod() {
      this.display = true | false; // (whatever) works fine, directive recevied that display was changed
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.display = false; // directive doesn't handle it
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
}

<div
    [show]="display"
  >1</div>
```

directive:

```js
export class TooltipDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() show = false;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // get changes from component made in other methods
    // doesn't get changes made in ngOnDestroy method
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to match what documentation tells for `ngOnDestroy()`:

> Called immediately before Angular destroys the directive or component.

I would put emphasis on "immediately" and wouldn't expect that another round of change detection is run afterwards.

It is not clear what you try to accomplish, but it sounds like a hack.